# A function to copy folder along with its contents python

Tags: python, copy

Hi is there a function that copies a parent folder along with all its content to a specified destination in python.

I have used different functions but they seem to copy the contents excluding the parent folder.

Many thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`shutil.copytree` comes to mind immediately, but your issue is that copying directory `foo` in `bar` doesn't create `bar/foo`.

My proposal:

```
import shutil,os

def copytree2(source,dest):
    os.mkdir(dest)
    dest_dir = os.path.join(dest,os.path.basename(source))
    shutil.copytree(source,dest_dir)
```

- first create destination
- then generate destination dir, which is the destination added source basename
- perform `copytree` with the new destination, so source folder name level appears under `dest`

There's no subtle check about dest directory already exist or whatnot. I'll let you add that if needed (using `os.path.isdir(dest)` for instance)

Note that functions from `shutil` come with a note which encourages users to copy and modify them to better suit their needs.

Answer (score 1):

In python 3.* we can use `shutil`

```py
import shutil

old_folder = "D:/old_folder"
new_folder = "D:/new_folder"
shutil.copytree(old_folder, new_folder, dirs_exist_ok=True)
```

`dirs_exist_ok=True` is for ignoring the exception when the folder already exists in the new location.

Answer (score 0):

Simply append the source directory you want to copy in the destination:

```
import shutil

shutil.copytree("source", "destination/source")
```

If you do not have fixed strings then use os.path.basename() to determine basename and combine it in the destination with os.path.join()

```
import os.path
import shutil

source = "/Projekte/python/source"
shutil.copytree(source, os.path.join("destination", os.path.basename(source)))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import shutil
shutil.copytree(srcDir, dst, symlinks=False, ignore=None)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Not to mention this does not solve the problem, because it does not create the target directory.